# Как в опредеоённое место текстового файла записать данные из переменной ?

Tags: pascal

```
1111
2222
3333
4444
5555
```

Данные из переменной должны будут записаться между 3333 и 4444. Ещё интересно узнать как 3333 заменить на 7777.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В любом случае придется делать это вручную. То есть: считывать с файла, пока не встретим нужное место. Дальше если нужно заменить, то можно просто записать 7777 (тогда четыре символа с текущей позиции заменятся на 7777), если нужно вставить, то придется запомнить все до конца файла и перезаписать.

Answer (score 0):

Несмотря на то, что [@Андрей](/users/202/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9) прав, я все равно хочу посоветовать метод seek(f, n). Он передвигает внутренний указатель файла(f) на позицию(n). Хотя это вашу проблему не решит.
Pascal не способен работать с файлами динамически, поэтому получить всю структуру файла придется по любому, а изменять её и перезаписывать в файл - это уже в коде программы.

Comment: По поводу `seek`: вначале мы не знаем `n` и функция бесполезна, но при поиске места, в которое мы хотим вставить, эта функция может пригодиться, чтобы сделать шаг назад, когда мы найдем нужное место.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример кода на Delphi для этой задачи:

```
Var
  Mas: Array[0..999] Of Integer;
  FF: TextFile;
  i, n: Integer;

begin
  AssignFile(FF, 'file.dat'); // в Паскале так: Assign(FF, 'file.dat');
  Reset(FF);

  i:=0;
  While Not(Eof(FF)) Do
    Begin
      ReadLn(FF, Mas[i]);
      Inc(i);
    End;
  N:=i;

 // CloseFile(FF); Возможно, в Паскале нужно будет написать Close(FF);
  Rewrite(FF);

  For i:=0 To N-1 Do
    If (Mas[i]=4444) Then
      Begin
        WriteLn(FF, 7777);
        WriteLn(FF, Mas[i]);
      End
    Else
      WriteLn(FF, Mas[i]);

  CloseFile(FF); // В Паскале нужно будет написать Close(FF);

  WriteLn('Vse normalno!..');
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Разобраться не составит труда: теорию Вам уже разжевали.

Comment: Вы правда считаете, что стоит так делать? Предвижу первый вопрос доцента: а что будет если файл содержит больше тысячи строк? и второй туда же: а что будет если файл пару-тройку десятков гигов? Вердикт будет: "в корне неверно".

Comment: Я просто привёл пример, а как именно делать должен дотуткать человек, который задал вопрос. Если это учебное задание, то этого вполне достаточно! В реальных случаях, конечно, же нет!

Comment: Просто преподаватели, давая задание, преследуют другую цель нежели внесение изменений в файл - научить человека думать как будет правильно. С этим приходилось сталкиваться в институте - программа у человека работает правильно, в том числе на синтетических тестах, а код неверный, так не пишут.

Не принимайте на свой счет, просто вспомнилось, захотелось поделиться ))

Comment: В принципе, согласен. В институте просто показывают синтаксис, а как правильно писать, догадывайтесь, ребятки, сами! И у нас так было, даже хуже: синтаксис объяснили неполно, неподробно. В любом случае без самообразования никуда!

Answer (score 0):

Мои 2 копейки. Если файл открыт на запись, то можно заполнять то место, к которому придется вернуться, когда запись подойдет к концу, необходимым количеством знаков и запоминать это место. В нужный момент (перед закрытием файла, например) вернуться и заполнить уже правильно. Я так делал, когда в шапку файла приходилось записывать среднюю величину или число записей.